# Closed form for the indefinite integral of the Jacobi Theta function

Tags: elliptic-functions, theta-functions

I am interested in the indefinite integral of $\vartheta_3(q;0)$. A lazy result gives us

$$
\int\vartheta_3(q;0)\mathrm{d}q=q+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{q^{n^2+1}}{n^2+1}+C.
$$

While there is nothing wrong with this lazy result, I am curious if there is a closed form expression.

Comment: Which Jacobi theta, $1,2,3$ or $4$ ?

Comment: @K.defaoite 3. I edited the question accordingly. Thank you!

Comment: While hardly definitive, Mathematica entirely refuses to integrate this. Nor can I find any such results in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik's tables of integrals (indefinite or definite). So that bodes poorly.

Comment: @Semiclassical Wolfram Alpha is more cooperative. It explicitly says "no result found in terms of standard mathematical functions" :) You can convert your comment to an answer and I can accept it in a week or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not definitive, both Mathematica and Wolfram Alpha entirely refuse to integrate this. Moreover, I can't find any such results in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik's tables of integrals (indefinite or definite). So that suggests that the series expansions or approximations seem the best hope. Conveniently the series will converge rapidly for most $-1<q<1$, slowing down only as $q$ approaches $1$ from the left.

In particular, the series converges as $q\to -1^+$. Moreover, while Mathematica fails to compute these integrals directly, it actually can resum this series when $q=-1$. Given that the series evaluates to zero when $q=0$, one deduces the definite integral

\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^0 \vartheta_3(q;0)\,dq 
&= 0-\left[-1+2\sum_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n^2+1}}{2n+1}\right]\\
&= 1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^2+1}\\
&=1-1 +\pi \operatorname{csch} \pi\\
&=\pi \operatorname{csch}\pi
\end{align}
which is remarkably simple and agrees in value with Mathematica's own numerical integration.

Comment: Why do you answer questions you considered not worthy to upvote? - I did it for you.

Comment: @niloderoock He(she) didn't answer actually, he commented. I persuaded him(her) to turn the comment into an answer, because it is not easy to get a "no, there is no such thing" type of answers :)